# Social login - permissions

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I have a question regarding angular boilerplate and the way social logins can be implemented. From what i gathered, we can bypass the default authorization which is defined in the "AuthConfigurer.cs" eg.

```
`if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:IsEnabled"]))
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
             }).AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", options => .........
                {`
```

and then when we try to login we validate the user with username and password so that we can return the result model with the bearer token and user id.

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model)
    {
        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            model.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
            model.Password,
            GetTenancyNameOrNull()
        );

        var accessToken = CreateAccessToken(CreateJwtClaims(loginResult.Identity));

        return new AuthenticateResultModel
        {
            AccessToken = accessToken,
            EncryptedAccessToken = GetEncrpyedAccessToken(accessToken),
            ExpireInSeconds = (int)_configuration.Expiration.TotalSeconds,
            UserId = loginResult.User.Id
        };
    }
```

Seems pretty straightforward but while looking at examples and suggestions i found on the forums we can use numerous ways to handle authentication eg.

```
if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:IsEnabled"]))

services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
});
```

So my real concern or rather my problem is if we bypass the bearer token and change it to something like Microsoft and we authenticate the user, what next?

How can we put permission for various pages on this authenticated "user"?

Can we set up authorization without a real boilerplate user who has permissions and if so, what then? How do we access parts of our website?

Comment: A user who can be assigned permissions is created, just like any other application that allows social login.

Comment: I see, but do you mean we have to manually create a new user or does boilerplate take care of that?

Comment: The ASP.NET Boilerplate template takes care of that.

Comment: I am not sure i understand you completelly, because lets imagine a scenario in which you have a boilerplate user with their roles(permissions) and you try to give the newly authenticated office user roles. How can you know which roles to give to the new user?  Can you combine those users or is the new office user already written in the database?

Comment: You cannot combine those users.